# как в инструментах разработчика сделать симуляцию прикосновения как на мобильном телефоне

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, инструменты-разработчика

Собственно, по теме вопроса и так все понятно. Я не смогла найти такую функцию - симулирование прикосновения на мобильном телефоне, но чтобы на компьютере можно было протестировать. Подскажите. пожалуйста, где ее искать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перейдите в мобильный режим (иконка ноутбука и телефона) или комбинацией `Ctrl+Shift+M`, когда у вас уже открыты инструменты разработчика.

Помимо того, что в этом режиме можно смотреть брэйкпоинты и проверять адаптивность, курсор превращается в окружность. Вот как раз на него реагируют все touch-эвенты.